# How can I tell if the first cell of DatagridView is null?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I want to check if the first cell of the row selected is null for a datagrid view. How would I go about doing that?

I tried:

```
DataGridView dgv = ..... ;
dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.Equals(null)
```

but then it throws a null reference exception. Is the best way to check if the row is null to check for the exception or is there another  way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Value is an object you can't call a method `.Equals(null)`  on a null object.  just do something like this

```
dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value == null;
```

you can use  the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
 Object obj=  dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value??"Cell is null"
```

Comment: `dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value is null;` will cause an error

Comment: Thanks. I cant believe I forgot about that.

Comment: @JulieShannon `Type expected`